# Checking if a unicode quotation mark is opening or closing

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

I am writing a lexer that needs to find the boundaries of strings. These strings may be quoted using Unicode characters (i.e. left `“` and right `”` double quotation marks) that can differentiate things such as strings-within-strings.

To test Unicode character properties I am using the ICU4C library.

I currently test for quotation marks using `u_hasBinaryProperty(cp, UCHAR_QUOTATION_MARK)`.

This works well for finding the quotation marks themselves, but falls short in being able to tell an open-quote from a close-quote.

Is there some property value I can test or other functionality I can use to test the orientation of the quote mark without explicitly testing it against each possible type of quote?

Comment: ... why is the obvious solution (testing it against the Unicode open quote codepoint) not viable? I'm not Unicode expert, but I was under the impression that there was only one open quote codepoint, right?

Comment: @NicolBolas It just feels 'wrong' or 'un-unicode' to test against individual characters rather than their properties. It might be just that I have to bite the bullet and do it using codepoints.

Comment: Perhaps you're misunderstanding the point of Unicode properties. For example, the "quotation mark" property is there to tell whether a codepoint is a quotation. That's it. Properties don't exist to be able to uniquely identify every facet of a codepoint. You can't tell everything about U+0041 just by examining its properties.

Comment: @NicolBolas Most codepoints have more than a single property and those properties can be non-binary (e.g. the numeric value property). I'm basically asking for a "which direction" property that applies to quotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a quotation mark is opening or closing is language/locale dependent and therefore out of scope for Unicode. Unicode deals with scripts only. Examples:

- «Swiss»
- »Polish«
- »Finnish»

Look elsewhere.